# How to implement seamless clipboard between Explorer and TcxShellListView?

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-xe2, clipboard, explorer

I have an application that mimics Windows Explorer, it uses a `TcxShellListView` amongst other shell controls.

A really nice feature would be to be able to `Copy & Paste` and `Cut & Paste` files between the real Windows Explorer and my application.

`Drag & Drop` already works out of the box, but it seems that DevExpress hasn't implemented the clipboard side, yet.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to implement the copy/paste yourself, the mechanism is almost identical to drag and drop. The drag and drop code that you have will create an `IDataObject`. To copy, instead of calling `DoDragDrop` to initiate a drag, simply call `OleSetClipboard` passing the `IDataObject`. And for pasting you call `OleGetClipboard` to get the `IDataObject` from the clipboard. And then you simply use the exact same code as for a drop operation to decode the `IDataObject`. That's all there is to it.

There is another way to do it, probably a better approach in my view. And that is to use `IContextMenu` to do the work. And example of this can be found in the TurboPower tpShellShock project. Have a look for `ShellMenuExecute` in the `StShlCtl` unit. So long as the DevExpress component is using the shell interfaces, i.e. `IShellFolder`, then you will be able to use that same approach. The advantage of this shell based approach is that you are getting the shell to do the work. If a copy dialog needs to be shown, then the shell will do so. This will give you the most integrated user experience.

This code looks like this:

```
procedure ShellMenuExecute(
  const Sender : TObject; const Folder : IShellFolder;
  var Pidl : PItemIDList; const Count : Integer;
  const AHandle : THandle; ClipboardAction : TStMenuAction);
var
  CM : IContextMenu;
  CI : TCmInvokeCommandInfo;
begin
  if Folder <> nil then begin
    if (Folder.GetUIObjectOf(AHandle, Count, Pidl,
      IID_IContextMenu, nil, Pointer(CM)) = NOERROR)
    then begin
      ZeroMemory(@CI, SizeOf(CI));
      CI.cbSize := SizeOf(TCmInvokeCommandInfo);
      CI.hwnd := AHandle;
      case ClipboardAction of
        caCut   : CI.lpVerb := 'cut';
        caCopy  : CI.lpVerb := 'copy';
        caPaste : CI.lpVerb := 'paste';
        caProperties : CI.lpVerb := 'properties';
      end;
      CM.InvokeCommand(CI);
      CM := nil;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

I think you should be able to use this code pretty much as is. I would point out that the handle parameter is declared incorrectly. It should be `HWND`. It's used as the owning window for any dialog that is shown during the call to `InvokeCommand`.